# Conflict in code between two JS Libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use two different libraries on a single webpage -- [Materialize.css](https://materializecss.com/) and [JQuery EasyUI](https://www.jeasyui.com/) -- but their code seems to be interfering with each other and I'm running into errors. Is there any way I could ensure their codes do not conflict with each other and each run separately?

I guess using an iframe could be a solution here, but that would introduce other problems for me. Is there any other way I can ensure they both run on the same page in harmony?

EDIT: I should point out that I'm using the functionalities of each of of the libraries in two different sections of the page. More specifically, the Materialize.css is used for the navbar, text and the general look of the page whereas I'm using JQuery EasyUI just to display an editable datagrid.

Comment: CSS conflicts or Javascript?

Comment: both, but I could take care of the CSS conflicts. The JS, however, seems to be pretty impossible to solve. @Stefan

Answer (score 1):

Typically it is impossible to prevent conflicts between libraries that you yourself do not write/manage. If they don't have a means of preventing a conflict (like jQuery's `jQuery.noConflict()`), you just have a problem, except if you use module bundlers like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) which enables to load modules under different aliases so that they don't conflict.

Comment: That being said, maybe if you could provide us with what exactly the conflict is, we could possibly provide more insight.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! and as for the specific problems, I'm actually running into pretty random errors. Like for instance, when I'm trying to make the datagrid editable, the code run from the JQuery EasyUI library is calling some function on the Materialize.css library and that's throwing an error.

Comment: Sounds like bad library design if two different libraries call functions outside of their "namespace". But unfurtunately it's you finding yourself with the problems here. In your case I would check the source code for where these functions are being called and see if there is no smart way to build/wrap around it. If there's not, you're gonna have to either contact the package managers or do something else smart.

Answer (score 0):

Materialize and jQuery both use the $ prefix. Instead of using `$.noConflict();`, try assigning jQuery to a new variable as a prefix:

`var jq = $.noConflict();`

Then you'll be using jquery with the variable name as prefix, ex:

```
jq("div").click(function(){
    //do something
});
```

Comment: could you please elaborate?

Comment: got it! but their codes are automatically interfering when I'm including both libraries on the same page. The errors don't necessarily come up after I've written any code.

Comment: Cause something of the libraries is running on the pageload! try to execute the reassignament on the page load or jquery ready and see what happen